# gocd - Agent never doing second pipeline stage/job

Tags: continuous-integration, pipeline, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, go-cd

i have install [GOCD](https://www.gocd.org/) (*Go continuous delivery*) on my Ubuntu VPS with its agent (`Go-Agent`) on same server.

One pipeline (**the 1st**) have been created and it run smoothly to do any stage/job/task, there's one agent that always to do the job:

[image]

but when i try create new pipeline, i dont know why no agent wont work to `2nd pipeline`. i just see message:

> **Not yet assigned**

screenshot :

[image]

try wait up to one hour, but the agent never working for 2nd pipeline job.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons why no agent might be assigned:

- The job specifies resources that no agent has
- The pipeline is not in the same environment (or not at all in an environment) that an agent is in.

So please double-check the pipeline's and agent's environments and the resources.

I hope this helps!

Comment: the 2nd pipeline just clone of first one. any idea ?

Comment: @anunixercoder  I don't know if cloning a pipeline clones the environment it is in as well. Please double-check that!